# How to get the actual width of a rotated canvas rectangle

Tags: javascript, canvas, konvajs

I'm using konva js to make a [transformable rectangle](https://konvajs.github.io/docs/select_and_transform/Basic_demo.html/). I'm able to access the width of the rectangle using 
`rect1.getClientRect().height`
. However, when I rotate the rectangle, the width property is changing. I believe width property gives the overall horizontal length of the container of the rectangle canvas. Is there any way I can get the actual width of the rotated rectangle. Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Rookies/8gack34s/1/)

Comment: Could you clarify what you need? Your rectangle is 100 x 90. When you rotate the rectangle the width of the shape will remain 100. The getClientRect will give the width of the bounding rect which will be different, naturally. So what is it you want to know? I honestly want to help but its not clear what you need.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat Sorry for the late reply. I need the width of the shape rather than bounding rectangle after it has been transformed. The example I provided gives the width of the bounding rectangle rather than the width of the shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Konva-object has an `attrs` attribute: `rect1.attrs.width * rect1.attrs.scaleX`

https://jsfiddle.net/8gack34s/4/

there is also `attrs.rotation` that you can use to calculate it mathematically.

> Konva warning: Konva.Transformer is currently experimental and may have bugs. Please report any issues to GitHub repo.

Comment: I have increased the size of the rectangle, but it's still showing 100,19(Not the size of the updated rectangle)

Comment: Then try `rect1.attrs.width * rect1.attrs.scaleX`